# SELECT Query by avoiding a specific row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with many columns. Each row contains a unique ID field. How can I select 5 rows without selecting a row with id stored in variable $doNot.

Currently I am using the following query.

```
$qry="SELECT title, link FROM posts WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) - 5 FROM news)";
```

Consider this table:

```
id      |    title      |     link
_____________________________________
1       |   title_1     |     link_1
2       |   title_2     |     link_2
3       |   title_3     |     link_3
4       |   title_4     |     link_4
5       |   title_5     |     link_5
6       |   title_6     |     link_6
7       |   title_7     |     link_7
8       |   title_8     |     link_8
```

I want to `select 5 rows except row with id '3'` using the above query from the above table

Comment: Try to post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: You have a 'table'

Comment: @Forward I have updated my question

Comment: `$qry` makes me assume you are using php. `$doNot` is a php variable? If so, please flag your question with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT title, link FROM posts WHERE NOT (id = $doNot) LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to specify the number of rows to be returned:

```
SELECT title, link
FROM posts
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If $doNot is a table variable, you should be able to simply sub-query on posts.id:

```
SELECT title, link FROM posts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM $doNot) LIMIT 5;
```